# how to append script file in zend framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-layout

My layouts are placed inside layout/scripts/layout.phtml
i have placed the below code inside my head section of layout.phtml

```
<?php
print $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')
                         ->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/simpla.jquery.configuration.js');
?>
```

Now I want to append another javascript file from a view. For that I wrote the following code:

```
 $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js');
```

Although this appended the file but it appears before my jquery-1.7.2.min.js. What i want is that i want to add jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js below my jquery-1.7.2.min.js
How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view script is rendered before the layout so the calls to `appendFile()` in your layout result in those scripts (jquery-1.7.2 and simpla.jquery) being appended after the one you appended in the view script.

To fix this, use `prependFile()` in your layout at least for the main jQuery script.

Your layout might look like this:

```
<?php
print $this->headScript()
           ->appendFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/simpla.jquery.configuration.js')
           ->prependFile($this->baseUrl().'/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js');
```

No need to change the view script, that is fine as is.

See [HeadScript Helper](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.headscript) Example #23 which talks a bit about ordering of the scripts.

The important thing to remember that they don't mention is that your view script gets rendered before the layout does.